# how to get base_url() in controller codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, href, base-url

I'm trying to make a button in my table. i'm using datatable, so I declare the row inside the controller. I want to give my button a `href`, so then when the button was pressed, it will link to another controller to display another view.

this is my button in `PersonilController.php` :

```
//add html for action
$row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href=" . "' . base_url() . "/DetkelController/getpersid/" . $pers->id . '" title="Detail" ><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
```

but, the link leads me to my default controller:

```
http://localhost/polda_pensiun/PersonilController/
```

while I set my base_url on `http://localhost/polda_pensiun/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this seems quotations issue if not work let me know

```
$row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="'. base_url() . '/DetkelController/getpersid/'.$pers->id.'" title="Detail" ><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>'
```